# jQuery datepicker doesn't load in backgrounded selenium window?

Tags: jquery, python, selenium, datepicker

I'm trying to use Selenium in Python to programmatically check rental car prices on **[m.enterprise.com](http://m.enterprise.com)**. On this site, users select the start and end dates for car rentals with a **jQuery Datepicker 1.8.14 widget**.

---

**This Works:**

Here's an example website that has a jQuery Datepicker widget: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerClickInput.html

This is Datepicker 1.5 instead of Datepicker 1.8, but it should work as a toy example.

Let's try clicking on the Datepicker widget in Selenium...

```
defaultSleep = 3 #seconds
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url='http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerClickInput.html'
driver.get(url) # datepicker example
time.sleep(defaultSleep)
driver.find_element_by_id('date1').click() # THIS WORKS -- calendar appears.
```

The above example works properly. When we use Selenium to click on a datepicker element, the **calendar appears**, and the HTML code for the calendar gets generated. This example works regardless of whether the Selenium-driven Firefox window is in the foreground or the background.

---

**This doesn't work unless the Selenium-driven window in the foreground:**

Moving on from our toy example, let's use Selenium to do the first few steps of a rental car reservation on [m.enterprise.com](http://m.enterprise.com). Enterprise seems to pay attention to the previous page when clicking through these menus, so it's important to (automatically) click through the car reservation menus in order. (If we try to skip some pages or go out of order, Enterprise tends to throw a "session timeout" error.)

```
# PAGE 1: top-level page 
driver.get('http://m.enterprise.com/index.html')
time.sleep(defaultSleep)

# PAGE 2: fill in location where you want to reserve your car
driver.get('https://m.enterprise.com/reserve-car.html?restart=true&cm_sp=Reserve%20a%20Car-_-Body-_-en')
time.sleep(defaultSleep) 
element=driver.find_element_by_class_name('textInput') #place to type your Pick Up Location
element.send_keys("92093") #zip code or city/state
driver.find_element_by_class_name('buttonRight').click() # "Next" button 

# PAGE 3: select location within search results /reserve-car.html
time.sleep(defaultSleep)
# by making no input here, we default to selecting the first rental location in the list
driver.find_element_by_class_name('buttonRight').click() 

# PAGE 4: DO THE DATEPICKER. (choose time and date of car rental)
time.sleep(defaultSleep)
driver.find_element_by_id('datepickerPickup').click() #click on a datepicker
```

The `...('datepickerPickup').click()` line has mixed results. After taking some notes on the behavior, I've boiled it down to two key scenarios:

**Scenario 1.** You've selected the Selenium-driven Firefox window with the mouse. You're just merrily watching Selenium run the browser. The datepicker/Selenium interaction works **flawlessly**. The calendar appears, and the calendar's HTML code gets generated.

**Scenario 2.** You're using the mouse to click on some windows that are unrelated to the Selenium job. The Selenium-driven Firefox window is in the background, but you can still see that Selenium is clicking through the menus. When Selenium reaches the datepicker page, it clicks on the datepicker. But, Selenium's click on the datepicker has no effect! The **calendar does not appear**, and the calendar's HTML code does not get generated.

**Why doesn't the datepicker calendar appear unless the Selenium Firefox window is in the foreground?**

---

Final notes:

- Why m.enterprise.com instead of ordinary enterprise.com? The mobile version just seems a little bit easier to work with.
- Why Firefox instead of Chrome or Safari? I have no real preference here... If there's a reason to try this in a different browser, I'd be happy to try it.
- I use a pretty brain-dead way of pausing/sleeping while pages load: `time.sleep()`. I've tried more sophisticated alternatives, such as `implicitlyWait()`, and I'd be willing to investigate this more.
- All of the above notes aside, it seems that the foreground/background window thing is the crux of the problem here.